# How many different max-heaps exist for a list of n integers?

Tags: data-structures, combinatorics, heaps

How many different max-heaps exist for a list of $n$ integers?

Example: list `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

The max-heap can be either `4 3 2 1`:

```
    4
   / \
  3   2
 /
1
```

or `4 2 3 1`:

```
    4 
   / \
  2   3 
 /
1
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I did not find a closed form, but according to this entry in the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/A056971) the sequence starts with

1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 8, 20, 80, 210, 896, 3360, 19200, 79200, 506880, 2745600, 21964800, 108108000, 820019200, 5227622400, 48881664000, 319258368000, ...

You can find a not-so-nice recursion in the OEIS database. Basically the idea is as follows. The root of an $n$-ary heap is always the maximum. The two subtrees hanging off the root are again maxheaps. Their size depends on $n$, is a bit tedious to compute the sizes $n_1,n_2$ (see the OEIS entry), clearly  $n_1+n_2=n-1$. We can now pick, which elements go to the left heap and which go to the right heap. There are ${n-1 \choose  n_1}$ ways how to distribute the elements. This gives the recurrence

$$ a(n)= {n-1 \choose  n_1} a(n_1)a(n_2).$$